# Javascript value of textbox into other html tag (td) onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, tinymce, textarea

I have some value in textbox and lower have the button.
Onclick I need to update the inside of  with this value (which will be HTML tags)
I have tried:

javascript:

```
<script>
function copyfunction() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('mytextarea');
    var preview = document.getElementById('html_preview');
    preview.innerHTML = textarea.value;
}
</script>
```

html:

```
<textarea id=mytextarea name=text>some initial text</textarea>
<button type=button onclick=\"copyfunction();\">Preview</button>

<table><tr>
    <td id=html_preview></td>
</tr></table>
```

but it doesnt do anything

EDIT: sorry for leaving escapes \ but im doing this in php, so:

```
echo "<button type=button onclick=\"copyfunction();\">Preview</button>";
```

- and it doesnt work, however when i do it in simple html, then it does :(

EDIT2: im sorry for all of your efforts, it work fine, however im implementing [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/quick-start/) and it doesnt work with this app :(

Comment: Please show us the complete php code and it's resulting html output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once TinyMCE is initialized and visible on the page the original `textarea` is no longer visible.  When you init TinyMCE it renders an `iframe` as the content editing area (effectively hiding the `textarea`).

If you want to extract the content TinyMCE you need to use the TinyMCE APIs to do so.  You can use `getContent()` to retrieve the current content of the editor:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent

For example:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
```

Here is a working example of how you could sync a neighboring DIV with the content in TinyMCE:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/HLgaab/5

Comment: In the fiddle, change innerText to innerHTML to see the content rendered by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Made some changes to your code and it works. In `onclick=\"copyfunction();\` you need to remove the `\`s

```js
function copyfunction() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('mytextarea');
  var preview = document.getElementById('html_preview');
  preview.innerHTML = textarea.value;
}
```

```html
<textarea id=mytextarea name=text>some initial text</textarea>
<button type=button onclick= "copyfunction()">Preview</button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id=html_preview></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave out those escaping backslashes in your HTML attributes.
Also you should put all attribute values in double-quotes.

```js
function copyfunction() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('mytextarea');
    var preview = document.getElementById('html_preview');
    preview.innerHTML = textarea.value;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="mytextarea" name="text">some initial text</textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="copyfunction();">Preview</button>

<table><tr>
    <td id="html_preview"></td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: i was 3 seconds too late :(