# How to get the HTML and CSS generated by tinymce

Tags: html, css, tinymce, editor

I recently started building an open-source blog for programmers.... I am work with tinymce... Can you tell me how to get the HTML and CSS file generated by tinymce editor

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: See the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62307269/167129) on how to retrieve the HTML from the editor.